# Start and Close a program in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am using this script to launch calculator program. How to add lines to close the calculator after 2 mins.

```
Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:")._
ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerManagementEvent")

Do
Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
If strLatestEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
For Each objItem in colItems
If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
ElseIf strLatestEvent.EventType = 7 Then 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "calc.exe", 1, false
End If
Loop
```